# I need stop a loop with setTimeout inside in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, for-loop, settimeout

i have a loop with setTiemout inside and i need stop it via onClick button

```
var loop = function(){
    for (var i = 0; i < tx.length; i++) {
        setTimeout((function(x) {
            return function() {
                $("#div").append(tx[x] + " <br />");
            };
        })(i), 500 * i);
    }
};

$("#start").on("click", loop);
$("#stop").on("click", stop);
```

i have the example in JSFiddle
[start|stop loop with buttons](http://jsfiddle.net/y4nEN/)

Thank's

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this?

```
var tx = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "g", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "y", "z"];
var run = true;
var txIndex = 0;
var loop = function(){
    if(run && txIndex < tx.length) {
        $("#div").append(tx[txIndex] + " <br />");
        txIndex++;
        setTimeout(loop, 500 );
    }
};

$("#start").on("click", function() { run=true; loop() } );
$("#stop").on("click", function() { run=false } );
```

[Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5Cnpw/2/)

Answer (score 4):

You'll have to retain pointers to the results of the `setTimout()` method so you can later call `clearTimout` on them.

If you need to break from the loop itself, you'll want to set a flag somewhere else in your code, then check the value inside of the for loop. If that flag is set, then `break`.

Answer (score 2):

Clean solution: http://jsfiddle.net/y4nEN/2/

```
interval = setInterval(function() {

    $("#div").append(tx[x] + " <br />");
    x++;

    if(x >= tx.length)
        clearInterval(interval);

}, 500);
```